# R How to match dataframes to retrieve elements

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have a dataframe with 5000 rows, containing municipalities data from which I need to extract only rows matching a specific set of names. I am iterating the set through my dataframe using for loop.

This is for R 3.6.0

```
data <- NULL
for (i in mun.names){
  data <- area.mun[area.mun[, 1] == i, ]
}
```

The object `mun.names` contain the municipalities I need to match. The object `area.mun` has the two columns `NAME` and `AREA`. The first column of both objects has municipalities names formatted accordingly.

At the end of the for loop my resulting object `data` always has only one value, the last municipality of the object `area.mun`.

This is a simple error. I appreciate any kind of feedback.

Comment: R 5.x? You must be from the future. Have a look at the `subset` function.

Comment: `data = area.mun[area.mun$NAME %in% mun.names]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your 'mun.names' to data frame:

```
mun.names <- data.frame(mun.names)
```

Change the column name to 'NAME':

```
colnames(mun.names) <- c(NAME)
```

Convert your 'area.mun' to data frame:

```
area.mun <- data.frame(area.mun)
```

Use merge command to extract the matched rows:

```
df <- merge(area.mun,mun.names,by.x="NAME",by.y="NAME")
```

You can also get all the unmatched rows from mun.names and area.mun data frames using all.x=TRUE and all.y=TRUE

```
df <- merge(area.mun,mun.names,by.x="NAME",by.y="NAME",all.x=TRUE, all.y=TRUE)
```

Comment: Almost there. The final data.frame `df` has some duplicates. `num.names` has 2122 rows, So `df`should have the same 2122 rows. Instead it got 2386 rows.

Comment: Then you should read the second last line which explains why you are getting duplicates. You can use: 
f <- merge(area.mun,mun.names,by.x="NAME",by.y="NAME",all.y=TRUE)

Comment: Same result yet. What else could it be?

Comment: How many rows you are getting with this:
df <- merge(area.mun,mun.names,by.x="NAME",by.y="NAME")

Comment: 2386 rows with: df <- merge(area.mun,mun.names,by.x="NAME",by.y="NAME") and 2386 rows with: df <- merge(area.mun,mun.names,by.x="NAME",by.y="NAME", all.y=TRUE). `num.names` has 2122 rows and `area.mun` has 5575 rows.

Comment: Is any of your data.frame has duplicate entries?

Comment: I´m not sure. That could be it. How to remove duplicated entries from `df`?

Comment: Use unique command and save your data into new data frame, then repeat the above command with your new data frame.
new_df <- unique(num.names)

Comment: These commands can also be used:
df1 <- area.mun[!duplicated(area.mun[c(1, 2)]),]
df2 <- mun.names[!duplicated(mun.names[c(1)]),]